# How to fix the footer to the bottom of the screen

Tags: footer

I've recently created my first Homepage (garageeden.at) with Wordpress using Elementor, and have a small issue with the footer (created with the header footer plugin for elementor). Currently it just follows after the content, so on pages with little content it sits in the middle of the page, with blank space under it.
I saw the suggestion of just adding

```
.site-footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
}
```

but if i do that using the custom css plugin it doesn't change anything

Comment: please contact the developer of your theme or plugin with your question. theme and plugin related question are nolt covered in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have with your CSS is that you are using .site-footer, but there is not such a class on your website, you should use #colophon instead.

```
#colophon {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
}
```

Check how the white space you mentioned goes on top of the footer.[image]